# Configuring glfw for Python in Eclipse

Tags: python, opengl, glfw

I'm trying to get OpenGL to work with Python. I'm using a python binding of glfw to display the window/configure the keyboard and such.

The [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyglfw/) page for pyglfw has a download link containing a .pyd file and a dll. On the [git](https://github.com/nightcracker/pyglfw) page, pyglfw contains a bunch of folders.

I downloaded both, and referenced them with PyDev in Eclipse, in the Eclipse "External Libraries" section. I wrote some code:

```
import glfw

glfw.Init();

if (glfw.OpenWindow(800, 600, 5, 6, 5, 0, 8, 0, glfw.FULLSCREEN) != True):
    glfw.Terminate(); # calls glfwTerminate() and exits
    glfw.SetWindowTitle("The GLFW Window");
```

And received this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Zolani\workspace\PyGLCanvas\main\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import glfw 
  File "C:\Users\Zolani\Desktop\pyglfw-main\pyglfw-master\glfw\__init__.py", line 395,     in <module>
    raise RuntimeError("no GLFW shared library found")
RuntimeError: no GLFW shared library found
```

I'm not sure what it's unable to find that it won't run. If I'm referencing the wrong directories within one of these folders, which ones do I need to reference in Eclipse's external library for it to find what it needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python modules must be installed in the right directories. Usually `$PYTHON/site-packages/…`. However why bother with doing all this manually. pyglfw is available through PIP.

`pip install pyglfw` takes care of downloading, building and installing the module.