# Using GLFW in Python on Windows

Tags: python, python-import, glfw, pyopengl, python-bindings

Is there an easy way to use GLFW in python?  I have tried installing pyglfw and wasn't able to import the modules inside of the pyglfw package.  I also tried installing glfw, but got the following error while trying to import it:

```
ImportError: Failed to load GLFW3 shared library.
```

I then tried downloading [glfw](http://www.glfw.org/) and placing the glfw3.dll file in the same directory as glfw.py but had no luck.  I am not very experienced with python imports or shared libraries, so its likely I made a mistake here.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: If it is any help, the following is the message given by the OSError exception:

```
[WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configure pyglfw](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34632537/configure-pyglfw)

Comment: @JohnY I have tried that but the solutions don't appear to work for me.  To clarify, I moved the glfw3.dll file into the SysWOW64 folder and changed how the library is loaded in the glfw.py module and still have no luck.

Comment: Incidentally, there are quite a number of Python bindings for GLFW. If I had to choose one today, it would probably be [this one](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/glfw) (which isn't the one covered by the question I linked to). But I don't use GLFW, so I don't have any tips of my own to offer.

Comment: @JohnY That is actually the one I am trying to use as well.  However, you need to download the DLLs separately from http://www.glfw.org/download.html and that seems to be the part I am screwing up, as the python binding can't load the libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by moving the lib-mingw folder obtained [here](http://www.glfw.org/download.html) into the same directory as glfw.py and then modifying glfw.py to load the DLL using the absolute path.